# Aptana crashes on Git Commit in 14.04

Tags: 14.04, java, git, oracle, aptana-studio

Ever since I upgraded my machine to 14.04 - I cannot commit via Aptana's "Team" menu.

I was having other, miscellaneous and unrelated problems, so I did a fresh install, and used Oracle Java instead, and I would've sworn to you that worked a couple of days ago.

But today, I'm having the same problem, and I can't find out why.

This is the error file it leaves behind ( `hs_err_pidXXXX.log` ), but I honestly can't make sense of it.. I don't see anything that defines precisely what the problem is... so I'm not even sure if it will be helpful...

http://pastebin.com/ZrCF26QS

I've tried: 
Installing

`tk8.5`
`python-tk`
`libswt-gtk-3-java`
`git-core`

The most recent thing I tried was 
`oracle-java7-set-default`
in case `oracle-java7-installer` wasn't enough.

I also ran:

`$ ulimit -c unlimited`

to no avail.

Any light anyone can shed on this would be greatly appreciated...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I got it working - 
//Edit : (My original fix wasn't actually what fixed it)

Oddly enough, one website suggested:

`ln -s /opt/Aptana_Studio_3/AptanaStudio3 /usr/local/bin/aptanaS3`

Which actually seems to be precisely what fixed the problem... 
Running Aptana via `aptanaS3` instead of `/opt/Aptana_Studio_3/AptanaStudio3` actually fixed the problem. 
I didn't originally mention it, because I thought I was just making a shortcut...

This is everything else I did, albeit I don't think any of this matters:

Added:
`-Dorg.eclipse.swt.browser.DefaultType=mozilla`

to `/opt/Aptana_Studio_3/AptanaStudio3.ini` at the very bottom...

Also did this, which I learned from [here](http://nikolas.demiridis.gr/post/14666354160/install-oracle-java-jre7-and-aptana-studio-3-on-ubuntu)

```
wget -O xulrunner.deb http://launchpadlibrarian.net/70321329/xulrunner-1.9.2_1.9.2.17%2Bbuild3%2Bnobinonly-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb && sudo dpkg -i xulrunner.deb
```

Comment: Well, after Aptana kept crashing on me for the last 2 days, i've found that many sites indicated that fix by adding the mozilla flag in the ini file. After reading this, i tried both solutions and only the mozilla flag actually reduced the crashes. Thanks for the heads up!

Comment: I tell you, since then, I've installed Eclipse from the Binary files (scroll way down on the d/l page - ) - and then install Aptana as a plugin -- the benefits have been great ---

Comment: Been thinking about that. I find Aptana to be sort of outdated as compared to Eclipse. Thanks for the tip